# How to select two elements with "> span" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my html code, I have the following two div elements:

```
<div id="graph-sliders">
...
</div>

<div id="image-sliders">
...
</div>
```

And in my corresponding css code, I have the follwing (working) code to style "graph-sliders":

```
#graph-sliders > span {
    ...
}
```

However, what I am trying to do is have that css block style both `graph-sliders` and `image-sliders`.  I have tried writing `#graph-slider #image-sliders > span {` but it messes up the formatting when I view the webpage.

What is the correct way to style both `image-sliders` and `graph-sliders` with the `> span`?

Comment: Multiple selectors should be separated by comma in css like `#graph-sliders > span, #image-sliders > span { ... }`

Comment: Try #graph-slider > span,  #image-sliders > span

Comment: Would `.sliders > span` be an option?

Comment: Muhammad Usman, I just tried your solution and it worked.

Comment: Martin Gottweis: That's a good point, but in my situation I can't use that because it would select elements I don't want to style.  I'll remove it from the question to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try the following:**

```
#graph-sliders > span, #image-sliders > span {
  ...
}
```